# regexp_substr with look behind Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle19c

I use the regexp_substr to get just 2 last characters in  strings like this
A-XY
XY

select regexp_substr('A-XY','([A-]+)?([A-Z]+)') from dual

this finds both string but I need to display just XY.
I tried to solve it with look behind in the first () like (?<=[A-]+) but it doesn't work and I got just an A as output.

Comment: Oracle doesn't support look-behind; what they do support [is in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Oracle-Regular-Expression-Support.html). Your two example strings don't need regex though - if you have more complicated strings (e.g. with following numbers that you want to ignore, or which might have only 1 character after a dash, etc.) then please edit your question to provide more representative sample data and expected output for  that data, and clearly explain the logic and rules you need to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the entire sub-string including the look-behind part (and anchor it to the end of the string using `$`) and then extract only the capturing group using the 6th argument to `REGEXP_SUBSTR`:

```sql
SELECT regexp_substr(
         'A-XY',
         'A-([A-Z]+)$',
         1,
         1,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS last_characters
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | LAST_CHARACTERS |
> | --- |
> | XY |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b2910609a070e397f3e99ed8e5b9dcb5)*